# mysql query with AND, OR and NOT

Tags: mysql, boolean, boolean-logic

Lets say I have a table of articles with as many to many relationship with topics. Each topic assigned to an article has a `type` field which can contain 1 of 3 values `AND`, `NOT`, and `OR`.

```
Articles
   id
   ....

Topics
   id
   ....

ArticleTopics
   article_id
   topic_id
   type
```

I want to create a query that says returns all articles that have:

```
ALL of the following topics: 1, 2, 3 (AND association)
   AND
ANY of the following topics: 4, 5, 6 (OR association)
   AND
NONE of the following topics 7, 8 (NOT association)
```

How do I go about creating this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope for work, I haven't done homework in about 12 years!

Comment: Is there a unique index on `ArticleTopics (article_id, topic_id)`? What is the exact meaning behind the `type` column? Why have a 'NOT' type, rather than simply not having an entry in the `ArticleTopics` table?

Comment: Also, for an article to be included in the results, does it need an OR association with all 3 topics (4,5 and 6) in the second restraint, or does it need an OR association with just one?

Answer (score 1):

The ALL and NOT parts are very simple, you just chain them with ANDs:

SELECT X FROM Y WHERE a AND b AND c AND NOT d AND e AND NOT e.

And the ORs go between:

SELECT X FROM Y WHERE ((a AND b AND c) AND (d OR e OR f)) AND NOT g AND NOT h

replace small numbers with comparisons and you're done.
So if you want to do this in code, sort your conditions and then just chain them together as a String. Be careful to avoid SQL-Insertions.

Comment: The fields are over a relation, so it is not as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly

```
    SELECT * FROM ArticleTopics where type = 'AND'
UNION
    SELECT * FROM ArticleTopics where type = 'OR' limit 1
```

I assume by 'any' you mean 'any one'. You can join the articles to topics yourself, that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name 
  FROM Articles a, ArticleTopics arto
  WHERE arto.article_id = a.id 
    AND 
      ((arto.topic_id = 1 AND arto.type like 'AND') AND (arto.topic_id = 2 AND arto.type like 'AND') AND (arto.topic_id = 3 AND arto.type like 'AND')) 
    AND
      ((arto.topic_id = 4 AND arto.type like 'OR') AND (arto.topic_id = 5 AND arto.type like 'OR') AND (arto.topic_id = 6 AND arto.type like 'OR'))
    AND
      ((arto.topic_id = 7 AND arto.type like 'NOT') AND (arto.topic_id = 8 AND arto.type like 'NOT'))
```

Comment: Note you can format lines as code by indenting them four spaces. The "101\n010" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.