# mysql has all values

Tags: php, mysql, select

This is relating to my last question [mysql query with AND, OR and NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153137/mysql-query-with-and-or-and-not)

Instead of editing the question, I am asking a new one because the question is only part of the previous question with an alteration.

I am looking to do a mysql query that returns me all articles that have all required topics.

```
Article
   id
   ....

Topic
   id
   ....

ArticleTopics
   article_id
   topic_id
   type
```

something that would effectively do:

```
SELECT * FROM Article LEFT JOIN ArticleTopics ON Article.id = ArticleTopics.article_id
WHERE ArticleTopics.topic_id HAS ALL (these topics)
```

Is this possible? What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several of the other answers suggest using aliases on the child table for each filter clause - this may not be very efficient or scale well.

Consider:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Article x INNER JOIN
(SELECT t.article_id, COUNT(t.article_id)
  FROM articleTopics t
  WHERE t.topic_id IN ([your_list_of_topics])
  GROUP BY t.article_id
  HAVING COUNT(t.article_id)>=[number of elements in [your_list_of_topics]]
  ORDER BY COUNT(t.article_id) DESC
  LIMIT 0,100) AS ilv
ON x.id=ilv.article_id
```

Another advantage of this approach is that the structure of the query doesn't need to change with the number of topics you are searching for - you could even put them in a temporary table and perform a join instead of using the ' IN (...)' literal.

You'd need to try it out to see which query behaves better.

Comment: Thanks this was perfect! I have it working great. Now I need to add extra so that it adds NOT and OR into the question see my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153137/mysql-query-with-and-or-and-not

Comment: So you are aware, it worked better as a string rather than a sub query

Comment: Wow! This is a great approach! I am really curious how much faster a `WHERE IN` is against an index compared to multiple `INNER JOIN` s. If MySQL optimizes things well, the difference should not be that big, it is basically the same lookup operation.

Answer (score 1):

That is done using multiple joins with the same table.

To select all articles that have topics with ID 1, 2 and 3, you need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Article a
  INNER JOIN ArticleTopics at1 ON a.id = at1.article_id AND at1.topic_id = 1
  INNER JOIN ArticleTopics at2 ON a.id = at2.article_id AND at2.topic_id = 2
  INNER JOIN ArticleTopics at3 ON a.id = at3.article_id AND at3.topic_id = 3
```

// EDIT
Fixed it. Added table aliasses; I must have been working with good ORM solutions for too long...

Comment: Please let us know whether this solution works! I wrote it a bit quick and might have make a mistake. Feel free to report it, I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Article
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ArticleTopics
        WHERE Article.id = ArticleTopics.article_id AND
        ArticleTopics.topic_id=1) > 0 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ArticleTopics
        WHERE Article.id = ArticleTopics.article_id AND
        ArticleTopics.topic_id=2) > 0 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ArticleTopics
        WHERE Article.id = ArticleTopics.article_id AND
        ArticleTopics.topic_id=3) > 0 AND
    ...
```

Comment: If I may comment, this query has to do quite a load of COUNT operations on an entire table, which can make it very slow on large datasets. (I don't think MySQL optimizes count() > 0). A lookup would be more efficient, I think.

Comment: Well, I think that in the end you are scanning the entire table in the same way in each of the solutions. MySQL guru needed :)