# mysql complex joins

Tags: sql, mysql, join

This is relating to [mysql query with AND, OR and NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153137/mysql-query-with-and-or-and-not) and also [mysql has all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153392/mysql-has-all-values) I have solved the `AND` part of the problem, but Now I also now need to solve the `OR` and the `NOT`.

Just to confirm the below statement gives me all articles that have each topic 1, 2 and 3

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Article x INNER JOIN
(SELECT t.article_id, COUNT(t.article_id)
  FROM articleTopics t
  WHERE t.topic_id IN ('1','2','3')
  GROUP BY t.article_id
  HAVING COUNT(t.article_id)>=3
  ORDER BY COUNT(t.article_id) DESC
  LIMIT 0,100) AS ilv
ON x.id=ilv.article_id
```

What I am trying to do is add something to the query that would exclude all articles that are also associated with topics 4 and 5. : `NOT`

I will also want to add the articles that have topics 6, or 7 as long as they match the previous constraints.

E.g.

```
SELECT all Articles where the articles has
    all the following topics (1,2,3) #AND
AND
    none of the following topics (4,5) #NOT
AND
    may have any of the following topics(6,7) #OR
```

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I don't see the point of looking for 6 & 7 if the requirement is that an article has to be associated to 1/2/3 first.  Sounds like ARTICLETOPCS is a many-to-many table, so anything related to 1/2/3 will be selected -- including those with additional links to 6 and/or 7.

Comment: so you need articles where (topic in (1, 2, 3) and not topic in (4, 5)) or topic in (6, 7)?

Comment: Seems like an ERD would be useful for this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Article x INNER JOIN
(SELECT t.article_id, COUNT(t.article_id)
  FROM articleTopics t
  WHERE t.topic_id IN ('1','2','3')
  AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM articleTopics
       WHERE article_id = t.article_id
       AND entity_id IN ('4','5'))
  GROUP BY t.article_id
  HAVING COUNT(t.article_id)>=3
  ORDER BY COUNT(t.article_id) DESC
  LIMIT 0,100) AS ilv
ON x.id=ilv.article_id
LEFT JOIN articleTopics at ON at.article_id = x.id
WHERE ae_topic_id IN ('6','7')
```

**This says all articles must contain all topics 1,2,3 and atleast 1 from 6 or 7 but never include 4 or 5**

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `EXISTS` function like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Article a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 1)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 2)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 3)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 4)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 5)
  AND (EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 6)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT topic_id FROM articleTopics t WHERE t.article_id = a.article_id AND topic_id = 7))
```

Comment: That would specify that the article has to be in topics 1,2 AND 3. Not OR. I don't think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: @cFreak I am looking for articles that have to be in all 3 topics

Comment: @Lizard: you should clarify the original question then. IN() is equivalent of OR so your AND logic isn't working.

Comment: Lizard wrote in the question "articles has
    all the following topics (1,2,3)", that was what I was going on.

Comment: I though I was clear enough, in fact my first query does exactly what I want, and returns articles that have all 3 topics, I need to add to the query where it excludes the NOT topics

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be much simpler to use a regular `JOIN` than to use a subselect. Should be faster too.

```
SELECT * FROM articles JOIN articleTopics USING(article_id) 
 WHERE topic_id IN(1,2,3) AND topic_id NOT IN (4,5) GROUP BY article_id;
```

I don't see why you need to specify 6 and 7. Unless you're saying if it has 6 or 7 the other rules don't matter. In which case you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM articles JOIN articleTopics USING(article_id) 
  WHERE (topic_id IN(1,2,3) AND topic_id NOT IN (4,5)) OR topic_id IN(6,7) GROUP BY article_id;
```

Comment: topic_id IN(1,2,3) would return articles that have any of these topics, I need where it has all of these topics. Same with NOT IN